# Assembler installation

Tags: assembly

I wanted to install a assembler for some use. Was suggested the borland turbo assembler or the microsoft macro assembler . But i couldn't install them because it says the version of the file isn't compatible with the kind of file you are trying to run. i hold windows 7. Could you suggest me an assembler and preferably its download link that has worked. 
PS: i have also tried the lazy assembler

Answer (score 3):

There is also FASM, which I've used a few times with great success.
http://flatassembler.net/download.php

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.10rc3/win32/nasm-2.10rc3-installer.exe)?

NASM is a [cross-platform assembler](http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.10rc3/), with versions for Linux/Mac OS X/Windows.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when developing assembler, you should be aware of the target processor architecture. Hence, you first step would be to find out what processor you are using. Then you might choose an assembler which supports your architecture:

- The GNU assembler supports many architectures: http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/as/
- For details on the MS Macro Assembler check out the Wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler
- If you have a 32 bit system, you could also check out the MASM32: http://www.masm32.com/

Cheers,

Martin.